# How to not display rows with null values when grouping data?

Tags: sql, mysql

I use MySQL. I have a database with data about employees in a company.

For every department I want to retrieve: department_id, number of emoployees in a department and number of employees, which get the salary > 6000$ in every department. I have a problem with the task about the salary, because I get NULL values and I would like to display only those that are not null.

My solution:

```
SELECT department_id, COUNT(*), IF(salary>6000, COUNT(*),NULL)
FROM employees WHERE department_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY department_id;
```

The problem is - I should get an outcome where no null values are present, now I get them in this column: IF(salary>6000, COUNT(*),NULL. I don't know whether my solution is wrong or it just needs adjustments. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` statement inside of `COUNT()` can be used to accomplish this rather than the opposite:

```
SELECT department_id, COUNT(*), COUNT(IF(salary>6000, 1, NULL)) as count_6000
FROM employees 
WHERE department_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY department_id;
```

Comment: It works well, thank you

Comment: Happy news:) If you think my answer is helpful, please vote/accept it.